# Sending POST data to REST service with authentication

Tags: java, rest, authentication, resteasy

I want to send JSON data to a REST service which includes authentication, but when I try to run this code, it throws a `RuntimeException` and HTTP code `302`. But the link is working fine through a REST client. I think my code is unable to provide the authentication details to the link.

I have tried so many combinations, but it's still not working. Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong?

```
JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(req); //JSON Object
ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING,
        Boolean.TRUE);
Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);
//Authentication filter
client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter("username", "password"));
WebResource webResource = client.resource(
        "http://licruleswb-dev.cloudapps.cisco.com/LicenseRules/rest/invokeRule");
ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json").type(
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).post(ClientResponse.class, obj.toString());
if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatus());
}
```

This is the error:

```
ERROR:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed :
        HTTP error code : 302
    at Test2.main(Test2.java:64)
```

Test2 is my class.

Comment: `302` usually indicates a redirection. Try setting `client.setFollowRedirects(Boolean.TRUE);`.

Comment: Did you try that `http://licruleswb-dev.cloudapps.cisco.com/LicenseRules/rest/invokeRule` is really accessible from the server where your code is running?

Comment: ya..It's working perfectly fine..I have tried so many times

Answer (score 0):

What framework are you using? Jersey? You can try setting the basic auth with:

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("username", "password".toCharArray());
            }
});
```

Comment: No,I am not using any framework.I tried the above method also.But,it's not working for me.

Comment: are you sure it is not jersey? where does the Client and the WebResource classes come from?

Comment: oh sorry.these classes are coming from com.sun.jersey.* package

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you use Jersey REST client. You need to be aware that this approach is deprecated in version 2.5 and removed in version 2.6. In higher versions of Jersey, you need to use this:

```
// Send with all calls
HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic(
                                               "username", "password");
```

or

```
// Send with a single call
Response response = client.target("http://...").request()
    .property(HTTP_AUTHENTICATION_BASIC_USERNAME, "username")
    .property(HTTP_AUTHENTICATION_BASIC_PASSWORD, "password").get();
```

See this link for more details: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html#d0e5181.

You could enable traces in your application or use an external HTTP proxy (like tcpmon) to see the actual sent request (if there is a header `Authorization` with content).

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: This is using org.glassfish package which is not compatible with my code as I have to use Java 1.5. can u suggest me some other thing